# Sharepoint workflows show as rejected eventhough everyone has approved

Tags: workflow

Two approvals via workflow show as rejected.  I don't know understand why as I believe everyone has provided their approval.
but  i could see one of the approver accidently deleted the doc and then again she added the doc and approved it under view workflow reports.

I believe that could be the reason for the rejection..AM not sure.. please clarify me.

Instead of recreating the workflow how make the workflow to be approved because we cant ask the people to approve it again.
Experts, please provide your inputs on this...

It would be nice if you update on this ASAP.

Answer (score 4):

If you created this in SharePoint Designer, try setting the variable "IsItemApproved" to yes.

1. Edit workflow
2. Change behavior of single task
3. Go to "When a Task Completes" step
4. In the first section "If current task:Outcome equals Approved"
5. Add a "Set Workflow Variable Action"
6. Choose "IsItemApproved" from the variable dropdown.
7. Set this variable to "Yes"

Answer (score 2):

The OOTB Approval workflow stop (by showing either Rejected or Cancelled) the process as soon as someone changes the document (including Deletion). Also, while configuring the workflow you get the chance to change to specify this behavior via a check-box.

Comment: Okay..thank you Marius..Instead of recreating the Workflow can we change the workflow status from Rejected to Approved?PLease help me on this..

Comment: Default behavior (as well as recommended practices) is as implemented, otherwise it defeats the whole purpose. If your intention is to change to Approved as soon as deletion (or change) occurs, one option would be to use the "Copy & Modify" option in SPD, change its behavior and deploy the updated WF where needed.

Comment: Glad I could help! Good luck