# Sharepoint workflows 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

I have had issues with workflows which are gradually sorting out.
Would some assist with an issue. I have change task outcomes buttons and now when the task is approved it appears as rejected. What do I need to change? Is there something in the behaviors of the workflow or the overall task? Output below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to my issues. See below:

Firstly, the issue of changing the button for the outcomes - I find in my SharePoint Designer that the edit mode (rename) function for current and new outcomes was very temperamental - did not easily go into edit mode - it took a lot of persisting to get this to work. This could be unique to my environment.

Once the buttons were changed I need to **Change the behavior of single task** and **Change the behavior of the overall task process** by editing under **When a Task Completes**. In this case I wanted the button text to read **Supported** and **UnSupported**. This was achieved by changing

**If Current Task: Outcome equals Supported**

**Else if Current Task: Outcome equals UnSupported**

I also needed to add under If Current Task:Outcome equals Supported a variable which I must contribute to [user23805](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/41370/sharepoint-workflows-show-as-rejected-eventhough-everyone-has-approved):

**Set Variable: IsItemApproved to Yes**. I hope this is of use to someone else who is looking to customize workflow a process OOTB.

[image]